# Are deeply nested if statements considered good form?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, coding-style

In my adventures of writing Mac software with Objective-C and Cocoa, I've learned quite a lot. There is still much for me to learn, but I've greatly improved in the past few months and have advanced to the point of programming software with moderate-high complexity.

Something that I've noticed is that throughout this time, the number of if statements (and to a lesser extent, for each statements) that show up in my code have increased dramatically. Sometimes, I find myself nesting if statements as far down as five statements deep.

I've not noticed any downsides to this myself (other than decreased readability in some cases), but is this considered acceptable and good form when writing Objective-C? Is there a better/more efficient way to accomplish things than nested if statements?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html

Comment: This question will clearly "solicit opinion, debate, [and] arguments".  How did it get an upvote?

Comment: @Carl: Potentially, except that I can't really imagine anyone arguing _for_ arrow code. This is pretty much an accepted guideline. I'd be more inclined to vote to close this as "you can read about this in any of a few dozen programming blogs", but that's not really a close reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deeply nested conditionals are certainly not considered *good* form. Whether they're really bad or not depends on your perspective, and perhaps a bit on the specific code. As you say, nested conditionals tend to be hard to read, and they also tend to be hard to understand and maintain.

Imagine if I gave you the following instruction:

*If it's Monday and if there's more than $30 in my account and if I'm not wearing a tie and if it's not raining out, I'd like you to go get me a cheeseburger for lunch. But if it is raining out, and if sauerkraut is available, I'll have a hotdog instead, but if there's no sauerkraut I'll just have a tuna sandwich. If I am wearing a tie I'll have a salad unless the reuben special is available, in which case I'll have that instead. If it's not Monday or if there's less than $30 but more than $12.50 get me tacos, but only if the good taco truck is nearby...*

That's just way too complicated an instruction to give to someone and expect them to get it right 100% of the time, even if you write it down. It's better if you break it down. You could write separate instructions on separate pages for each day of the week, for example. The code equivalent of separate pages would be separate functions or methods. Another way to simplify a set of complex conditions is to use a lookup table that lists all the combinations and the desired outcome for each. There are other possibilities too...

The main thing is: **don't write code that's hard to understand**. No matter what language you use, there will be plenty of tools at your disposal for simplifying the problem, so take advantage of them as best you can given what you know.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, nesting `if` statements beyond 3-4 deep begs for a different treatment.  Sometimes it's just a matter of combining conditions in one `if` (though you can go overboard on that too), sometimes it's a matter of creating some procedures, etc.

Often, when you find you have a lot of `if` statements, it indicates that you've let your main flow-control variables get too interrelated.  It's best if the main variables that you make decisions from are "orthogonal" as much as reasonably possible.  Ie, the fact that variable `X` is in state `A` doesn't "predict" what state variable `Y` will be in to any great degree.  (But of course, this "rule", like most in programming, is made to be broken, and should really only be used as a conceptual design aid.)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, I like to think of code in the same way I think of a sentence. When you have a run on sentence, sometimes the best solution is just to split the large sentence into smaller coherent thoughts.

Similarly with too many if statements, I would evaluate the function and see if you can break the it into more concise, smaller steps.

Another thing I've gradually become more aware of is the usefulness of Dictionaries in design. Not exactly sure why you would need so many if statements, but when in doubt, Dictionaries have always helped me in the past.

If you wanted to post an example of a case where you had many "if" blocks, perhaps it would help us provide a solution.